# Magento2 Installing custom search worked on luma but not in porto theme

Tags: magento2

I am trying to add this custom module to magento2 porto theme. It is working fine in installing on blank magento with luma theme. In my project i have installed Porto theme. When i install this module https://github.com/abdelkebir/magento2-search-autocomplete on porto, it is not working.
Her is default.xml of this cutom module
app/code/Godogi/SearchAutocomplete/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

```
  <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" >
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
            <referenceBlock name="top.search" remove="true"/>
            <!--
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="top.search" as="" template="Magento_Search::form.mini.phtml" />
            -->
            <block class="Godogi\SearchAutocomplete\Block\SearchAutocomplete" name="search.autocomplete" after="logo" template="search/autocomplete.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

The default.xml of Mageplaza_search module inside Porto theme, which i disable for now is this

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="top.search">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="mageplaza.top.search" template="Mageplaza_Search::search.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

[image]

[image]

Here your help is required. Thanks.